# android--unable to add listener to inflated table-

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a table defined in XML and a row defining a view as another XML. Let's say I need to populate the table with 5 rows. Running the following code:

```
  final ViewGroup table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);

  View row = null;

  TextView title = null;

  for(int i=0; i<5; i++)

  {

       row = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.row, null, false);

       title = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_title);

       title.setText("val");
       ImageView x= (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
       x.setOnClickListener(delimg);

       table.addView(row);

  }
  private OnClickListener delimg = new OnClickListener() { 


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pname);   
                    tv.setText("Deleted item!");  

    } 
};
```

It works fine but when i try to add onclicklistener to a image, it changes only the first row and not the corressponding row. please help.

Comment: Please edit your question or leave comments instead of posting answers that aren't answers.

Answer (score 0):

Where's itemView coming from?  Presuming the ImageView you want to set the listener for is inside your row, you might try changing from:

```
ImageView x= (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
```

to

```
ImageView x= (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.remove);
```

Does it work with that change?

---

EDIT: I think I made a wrong assumption on the problem here.  I thought you had a single TextView called pname, *outside the table*.  If you pressed the image on row 0, the text would update, but if you pressed row 1-4, nothing was happening.  I didn't see what would cause that.

I may have misread "it changes only the first row."  Do you have a pname in *each row*, and the text changes on the first row regardless of which row you click?  If so, then you need to change your onClick() to:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) arg0.findViewById(R.id.pname);   
        tv.setText("Deleted item!");
```

Otherwise, it's finding the first item with that id in the entire activity.